# CSS Works in Chrome, but breaks in firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have written a page in html and css. 
Here is the page: 
https://wheelertechconsulting.com/page1.html

I designed this page using chrome and when i uploaded to my website, I checked it out in firefox and noticed that that the ul li entrys in the the body div are compressed to the right.

What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found the solution, but you must correct the mistakes mentioned in my previous answer**

The problem is in :

```
.featured-images li {
    padding: 0 auto 1% 1%;
    border: .2em solid black;
    margin: 1%;
    ! height: 8em; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.8));

}
```

**If you comment this part of the code : `! height: 8em;` the problem will be resolved.**

Next image before comment `! height: 8em;`

[image]

**But after the comment `! height: 8em;` the appearance will become as in the following 
image**

[image]

**This part of the code is in the style file at the line 101.**

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  This seems to solve the problem.  I was in the process of rewriting the css using a different strategy.  This is a much more simple fix.  :) +1

Answer (score 1):

**You have many errors in the CSS file**

There is 6 errors and 12 warnings in your CSS file.

I used the [CSS online validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) to discover it

Try to fix those problems, maybe solve this problem.

You can see what the problem is and what line it will be in.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I was not aware of this tool.  I will correct the errors. :)

Comment: If the problem persists after correcting the errors, send me a link to which I can download the site files, Where I will try to find a solution.